# Spinner use IF else

Tags: android, android-spinner

i want to take the value in spinner and user press the ok Button and then start new activity from against the value of spinner. The string array is just like that.

```
 public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String[] array_spinner = {"Select Here", "Honda", "Toyota", "Mitibushi"};
    private String[] array_spinner01 = {"Select Here", "Civic", "Gli", "Lancer"};
    //    //private String[] array_spinner02={"1999","2000","2005"};
//    Spinner s,s1,s2;
//    Button ok;
//@Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner s, s1;
    Button ok;
    Object _globalString;
    Object _globalString2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner01);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
//
//    s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
//    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,array_spinner02);
//    s2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        s.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        s1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                _globalString2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            // @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_ok) {
            if (_globalString.equals("Honda") || _globalString2.equals("Civic")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Civic.class));
            } else if (_globalString.equals("Toyota") || _globalString2.equals("Gli")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Toyota.class));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

please tell me where is my mistake in this code because i stucked and i cant find it

Comment: why are you putting _globalString as an object not  a String

Comment: becuase save the spinner data in an object. so its the wrong

Comment: yes its wrong !

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but I would recommend to follow these solution :

First :

save the value of the spinner in a global string variable by declaring a string at the top of your Activity like below :

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Spinner s1, s2;
Button acceptbutton;
String _globalString ;
String  _globalString2 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//Your code ..
```

Now you need to save the value of your selected field into that string, everytime your spinner changes value :

```
 s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    _globalString2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Now you can switch activity based on spinner value :

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_ok) {
        if (_globalString.equals("Honda") || _globalString2.equals("Civic")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Civic.class));
        } else if (_globalString.equals("Toyota") || _globalString2.equals("Gli")) {
          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Toyota.class));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

whats the use of pos in this code

Comment: @harismahmood pos is the position taken from the override method onItemSelected . you can replace it by  position as mention . I will edit my answer

Comment: its not solving my problem still same issue

Comment: I've updated my answer for the last time . please consider understanding the concept not just copy and paste ! you have to compare based on the selection that you made  using _globalString variabale  .My answer is 100% correct

Comment: i cant copy your code i can pick your concept and then try on my code

Comment: please check it again my question i will updated it and tell me where is the mistake.